# Calling a stored procedure from db2 database to java code using spring

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from Java code. Procedure is working fine in DB2 but when I apply it with Spring and run java code, it is not inserting the record for which I wrote logic in stored proc.

Stored procedure code in DB2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MFAA.sample_pal(
IN Stmt varchar(2048)
) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 
--    declare      Stmt              varchar(2048); 
-- set Stmt = 'PALLAVI';
-- print Stmt;
-- select Stmt;
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value : '||Stmt);
insert into MFAA.DUMMYTABLE values(Stmt);
return 0;
END
```

java code:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;

import java.util.*;

public class callprocedure {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;
     private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;


    public JdbcTemplate getJdbctemplate() {

        ApplicationContext cx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("db2Context.xml");
        this.jdbctemplate=(JdbcTemplate) cx.getBean("jdbcTempDB2");
        return jdbctemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbctemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate) {
        this.jdbctemplate = jdbctemplate;
        //this.jdbcCall= new     SimpleJdbcCall(jdbctemplate).withProcedureName("sample_pal");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name="Pradeep";
     try
        {
         JdbcTemplate jt=new DbConnection().getJdbctemplate();              

          System.out.println("CALL STORED PROCEDURES");

          int rs=jt.update("call sample_pal(?)",name);
          System.out.println("Result : "+rs);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java code which has been shared we need to call the procedure with schema_name.proceure_name() then it works. So in the piece of code which is shared just change  `int rs=jt.update("call sample.sample_pal(?)",name);`

where `sample` is the schema name and `sample_pal` is the procedure name